# How to merge databases in one database in mvc entity frame work

Tags: mysql, database, entity-framework, model-view-controller, orm

Their are four databases in my same project of MVC. Now i want to merge the four databases into one database.

**Example:** I have four databases:

> (1) database1(containing 3 tables) 
>   (2) database2(containing 4 tables) 
>   (3) database3(containing 3 tables) 
>   (4) database4(containing 1 table)

Now i want only one database like:

> (1)database1 that contains all the above tables that's total counting if one database then 11

I have been given images below in the code section you can see this.

**Two databases and their table have been shown:**

[image]

**More Two databases and their table have been show in same project:**

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by merge into one database? Do you want to access them all using the same DbContext, is that what you're trying to say?

Comment: I want all the tables in one database. saw the images that I have been sent. i used orm(object relational mapping) and not used ms sql server. i created databases in visual studio.

Comment: i'm using database first entity framework

Comment: What's the question here?